# How to control the website with admin panel

Tags: php, html, css

first I'm so beginner .. I have learnt html and css .. I have some questions :

assume I'm the admin of some page .. I want also to allow users to upload files and articles but in another page in the website like here :

```
            <head>
                <title>azhargit</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
            </head>

                <body>
                    <h1>Azhargit</h1>

                    <ul>
                        <il><a href="index.html">Home</a></il>
                        <il><a href="">last topics</a></il>
                        <il><a href="">news</a></il>
                        <il><a href="">About</a></il>
                    </ul>
                </body>
            </html>
```

this is simple html page .. I want *admins* articles appear in *home* .. and *visitors* articles goes to admin panel so admin can approve them .. when they are approved .. It goes to *last topics* page .. **Can I do so only by php or have to learn any other languages ?**

sorry for my language .. Not English :D

Comment: yes, you can do this with php alone.

Comment: Before jumping into building something yourself, I recommend studying the language and working with existing projects to see how they work.  Come back to Stackoverflow when you have specific questions about coding errors.

Comment: As Devon Said you need to concentrate on learning things first ,get already built demo / sample solutions that may help you to understand . See the Samples and study them how they are working then do it yourself

Answer (score -1):

I think you just go with joomla Or wordpress both are a very powerful and famous CMS and easy to learn.